# iOS: how to receive Push Notifications when user force closes the App like Parse does?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, pushkit

I have a work-in-progress app that's not yet released, I was relying on Parse for Push in addition to my Backend, but since Parse is shutting down, it doesn't make sense to release it with Parse then change later.

Anyway, now I moved to GCM for iOS and from the code I see underneath you simply register for Push notifications (the normal iOS way) then once you get the Token you register it with GCM (Just like it used to be with Parse), but the biggest difference is that when I force-close the app Push notifications are never received, but when I had Parse and I force close the app, then I send Push notification I still get it, looking at what's underneath Parse's open source SDK (I couldn't understand everything, but I found no use of PushKit), Pushkit was suggested in few similar questions on the web. but there's no clear solution on how to achieve that.

Here's what I'm doing to register push:

```
// Register for remote notifications
UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Then:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"Application registered for remote notification");

    GGLInstanceIDConfig *instanceIDConfig = [GGLInstanceIDConfig defaultConfig];
    instanceIDConfig.delegate = self;

    [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] startWithConfig:instanceIDConfig];
    _registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                             kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@YES};
    [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:_gcmSenderID
                                                        scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM
                                                      options:_registrationOptions
                                                      handler:_registrationHandler];

    NSLog(@"This is device token%@", deviceToken);
}
```

Here's the push notification I'm sending:

```
curl --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --header 'Authorization: key=My-Google-Key' \
       https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send \
-d '{"to": "/topics/test","notification":{"sound": "default","badge": "1","title": "test title","body": "Test body", "dl": "myscheme://section/e5c7f33080940a95b94b50941e667da6", "content_available":true}, "data":{"alert":"breaking title","title":"breaking title","dl": "myscheme://section/e5c7f33080940a95b94b50941e667da6"", "content_available":true}}'
```

**To summarize things, I need a way to still receive push notifications if the app isn't running at all**

Comment: the notification payload does it have "content_available" set to true ?

Comment: yes, I tried with and without (no difference) will add Notification Payload

Comment: First you have two  "content_available" fields, remove both of them, and add it outside of 'data' and 'notification' fields, in the body root

Comment: I tried that but there's no difference

Comment: "content_available": "true" , have you put quotation marks on both key and value fields ?

Comment: that's not the solution, I found the solution, it was about the priority

Comment: @azimov thanks anyway, you helped with pointing to the area that would lead to the solution i.e. (The payload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution I'll leave it here in case someone else faced the same issue:

it was all about the "priority" key in the payload

**"priority":10**  means priority: **high**,

```
curl --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --header 'Authorization: key=My-Google-Key' \
       https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send \
-d '{"to": "/topics/test","priority":10,"notification":{"sound": "default","badge": "1","title": "test title","body": "Test body", "dl": "myscheme://section/e5c7f33080940a95b94b50941e667da6"}, "data":{"alert":"breaking title","title":"breaking title","dl": "myscheme://section/e5c7f33080940a95b94b50941e667da6"}}'
```

reference: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#priority

**side note: you don't have to duplication the "notification" and "data" this is just an example, it's not the real payload that I use in my app.**